# Sort objects by timestamp, but then group dependencies

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, grouping

Let's say I have a list (array) of objects. Each of these objects has two properties: a timestamp and an optional parent object, which can be null. I'd like to first sort this array by timestamps, which is easy enough; but then, I'd want the dependent objects to be kept consecutive.

For example, consider this simplified example: three objects, A, B, and C. B's parent is A, but the timestamps are A=1, B=3, C=2. Sorting by timestamp gives [A, C, B], but then because B's parent is A, I want B to come after A; so the ideal result should be [A, B, C] after all.

Note that if two or more objects have the same parent, they should all be adjacent, but they should be relatively sorted by timestamp still.

What's the best way to do this? This only way I can think is to sort by timestamp, then iterate through the array and, for each dependent object, move it after its parent; but that seems inefficient since it calls for an extra round of iteration. Is there some way to incorporate the grouping into the initial sorting so it can complete with only one round of sorting? (I'm currently using QuickSort, but if need be, I can switch to another algorithm.)

Comment: Side note: I think re-ordering the nodes after sort will not exceed complexity of sorting (if you are careful) so may be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force non-working approach - one option to perform sorting in one single operation you would need to make parent part of sort key in a following way and than sort by {order(Node.Parent), timestamp(Node)} pairs using any algorithm you like.

- "A is parent of B" => "order(A) < order(B)" and
- "C.timestamp < D.timestamp" => order(C) < order(D)

Unfortunately this "order" function requires sorting of all child nodes first to satisfy second condition thus breaking "one sort" requirement.

---

To get single sort you can use composite key that includes timestamps for all parent nodes and then sort by such composite key.

The easiest way to build composite key is to construct tree based on parent objects and set value of the key to be concatenation of parent's key and own timestamp using any [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Sample:

- Data

  ```
  A (ts = 5) parent of B (ts = 7),C (ts = 2)
  B parent of D (ts = 3)
  ```
- Building tree:

  ```
  A -> B -> D  
    -> C
  ```
- Pre-order traversal:  A, B, D, C
- composite key -

  A -> A.timestamp = 5
     B -> key(A) concat B.timestamp = 5.7
     C -> key(A) concat C.timestamp = 5.2
     D -> key(B) concat D.timestamp = 5.7.2
- data for sorting by {order, timestamp} pairs

  ```
   A {order(no-parent), ts} = {0, 5}
   B {order(A), ts} = {1,7}
   C {1,2}
   D {2,3}
  ```
- sorted sequences - {5}, {5.2},{5.7},{5.7.2} mapping back to nodes - A,C,B,D

Complexity of this approach is O(n log(n) max_depth):

- build tree/walk tree/build keys - O(n)
- sort is complexity of sort (usually O(num_elm log(num_elem)) multiplied by complexity of comparing keys which are depending on depth of parent-child tree. This part dominates O(n) needed for preparation phase.

---

Alternatively you can just build tree, sort each level by time-stamp and than put them back in a list via [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order), which removes complexity of key comparison but breaks requirement of single sort.

Comment: I'm willing to do two steps as long as the complexity isn't increased (or at the very least, not by much). But one question: in your ultimate suggestion of building a tree, sorting each level, and then listing the tree nodes again, how would I sort each level better than O(n log n * max_depth)? I'd imagine each level of the tree would need to be sorted independently, each taking O(n log n), right?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk yes, child nodes of each node will need to be sorted individually. Complexity of all sorts will be O(n log n) as maximum number of nodes to sort is n (single node can have only have one parent - so you never sort same node twice as they all in seprate groups by parent). Building (with hash table to find parents) and walking both O(n) so overall O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the objects into lexicographical order using a sequence of one or two numbers as sort key, where if an object has no parent it has a single element in the sequence which is its number, and if an object has a parent the first element in the sequence is its parents number and the second is its own number.

So A, B, and C get sequences {1}, {1, 3}, and {2} and B sorts just after its parent.

Comment: Side note: perfect for sample in the post when there is only one level of child node. If there is more than one level of parents you'd need to build tree first and key will be of variable length (steps in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43025162/477420)).